# Cannot install canopy from Enthought under Debian Wheezy Linux

Tags: python, linux, debian, canopy, failed-installation

I downloaded canopy for linux-32-i86 newest version then tried to install it on my linux-notebook (AMILO from ~2004) - however it produced the following error messages:

```
[...]
Installing to /ibk-varia/Canopy ... please wait
/home/kampmann/.local/share/applications/canopy.desktop: error: (will be 
fatal in the future): value "Science" in key "Categories" in group 
"Desktop Entry" requires another category to be present among the 
following categories: Education
The databases in [/usr/share/gnome/applications, /usr/local/share   
/applications, /usr/share/applications] could not be updated. is there 
anything wrong with these texts?????
Unknown media type in type 'unknown/mime-type'
done.

You can run the Canopy graphical environment by running the script:

    /ibk-varia/Canopy/canopy

or by selecting 'Canopy' in your Applications menu.

On your first run, your Canopy User Python environment will be
initialized, and you will have the opportunity to make Canopy be your 
default Python
at the command line. Details at support.enthought.com/forums

Thank you for installing Canopy!

WARNING: the PYTHONPATH environment variable is currently set.  This might
     cause unexpected behavior when running the newly installed Python
     interpreter.

kampmann@ibk-womo:/ibk-varia/newsoftware$
```

after this I run "canopy" but after some seconds of activity nothing was available. however the log file and some others showed:

```
runtime (2015-08-10):

Exception in thread Thread-3 (most likely raised during interpreter 
shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7 
        /threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7
        /threading.py", line 763, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/accounts/account_service.py", 
  line 390, in _check_authenticated_user_info
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/accounts/account_service.py", 
  line 278, in get_enstaller_user_info
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/accounts/account_service.py", 
  line 261, in get_enstaller_session
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/accounts/account_service.py", 
  line 253, in do_authenticate
  File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7
        /site-packages/enstaller/session.py", line 179, in authenticate
  File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7
        /site-packages/enstaller/auth/auth_managers.py", 
  line 47, in authenticate
  <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
        'exceptions'
kampmann@ibk-womo:/ibk-varia/Canopy$
```

and now:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3 (most likely raised during interpreter 
shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7 
        /threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7
        /threading.py", line 763, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/accounts/account_service.py", 
  line 390, in _check_authenticated_user_info
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/accounts/account_service.py",
  line 278, in get_enstaller_user_info
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/accounts/account_service.py", 
  line 261, in get_enstaller_session
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/accounts/account_service.py", 
  line 253, in do_authenticate
  File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7
  /site-packages/enstaller/session.py", line 179, in authenticate
  File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7
  /site-packages/enstaller/auth/auth_managers.py", 
  line 47, in authenticate
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
      'exceptions'
kampmann@ibk-womo:/ibk-varia/Canopy$ 

logfile - 2015-08-10:

INFO|2015-08-10 22:48:10,697|=============  Start bootstrap logging   
    =================
INFO|2015-08-10 22:48:10,717| current log file:   
     bootstrap_2015_0810_2248_10665007.log
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:15,411|loading preferences from </home/kampmann
      /.canopy/preferences.ini>
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:15,466|Disabling proxy support after preference 
      apply.
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:15,467|Disabling proxy support after preference 
      apply.
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:15,480|  proxy_info = {}; no_proxy =  
      localhost,127.0.0.1
INFO|2015-08-10 22:48:15,480|urllib2 using proxy = False
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:15,480|no HTTP proxy set up for Qt
INFO|2015-08-10 22:48:15,522|BOOTSTRAP: Running process manager  
    successfully created with application home at /home/kampmann/.canopy
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:15,608|Bootstrap already locked by dead process.
INFO|2015-08-10 22:48:15,609|Process that locked layers is dead with info 
    {'status': 'install', 'layer': 1}
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:15,609|Acquired bootstrap lock.
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:15,610|Wipe out /home/kampmann/Enthought
     /Canopy_32bit/System
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:19,594|---------- starting GUI event loop 
                             ----------
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:19,865|Wipe out /home/kampmann/Enthought
     /Canopy_32bit/User
DEBUG|2015-08-10 22:48:19,931|---------- starting GUI event loop 
                             ----------
INFO|2015-08-10 22:48:20,204|Bootstrap settings: {'_common_prefs': 
    <apptools.preferences.preferences.Preferences object at 0xb56c07ac>,
'_lock': <canopy.app.bootstrap.BootstrapLock object at 0xb46c746c>,
'_logging_setup': True,
'_not_start_app': False,
'_options': Namespace(batch_mode=False, common_install=False,  
       default=None, factory_reset=False, func=None, install_dir='',   
       launch_prefix='/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-
            1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86', no_gui_setup=False, profile='', 
            recovery_mode=False, safe_mode=False),
'_proc_manager':  
       <canopy.app.running_process_manager.RunningProcessManager object 
                at 0xb4724c0c>,
'_use_running_python_for_venv_ops': True,
'app_name': 'canopy',
'app_root': '/ibk-varia/Canopy',
'application_home': '/home/kampmann/.canopy',
'batch_mode': False,
'bits': '32bit',
'common_layer1': '',
'common_layer2': '',
'common_locations_cfg': '/ibk-varia/Canopy/locations.cfg',
'common_preferences_path': '/ibk-varia/Canopy/preferences.ini',
'company_name': 'Enthought',
'default_app_home': '/home/kampmann/.canopy',
'default_user_data': '/home/kampmann/canopy',
'esky_app': '/ibk-varia/Canopy/canopy',
'esky_appdir': '/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86',
'has_venv': True,
'is_esky_app': True,
'launch_prefix': '/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86',
'layer0_location': '/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86',
'layer1_location': u'/home/kampmann/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System',
'layer2_location': u'/home/kampmann/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User',
'no_gui': False,
'orig_app_name': 'Canopy',
'product_name': 'Canopy',
'profile': '',
'python_for_installer': u'/home/kampmann/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System 
                        /bin/python',
'python_l0': '/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/bin
                        /python',
'python_l1': u'/home/kampmann/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System/bin/python',
'python_l2': u'/home/kampmann/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/python',
'read_only': False,
'scripts_dir': 'bin',
'user_data': '/home/kampmann/canopy'}
INFO|2015-08-10 22:48:20,231|Creating venv in layer1: /home/kampmann
              /Enthought/Canopy_32bit/System
ERROR|2015-08-10 22:48:20,232|Unhandled IO/OS Error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/util.py", 
    line 270, in handle_common_io_errors
   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", 
    line 2400, in main
   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", 
    line 1351, in main
   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", 
    line 1533, in setup_layers
   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", 
    line 997, in _setup_layer
   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", 
    line 1266, in create_venv
   File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7
         /venv/__init__.py", 
    line 383, in create builder.create(env_dir)
   File "/ibk-varia/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7
         /venv/__init__.py", 
    line 94
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Exactly what is lacking in Debian's Python stack?

Comment: Thank for coming back, Dirk. Why? simply because I use this notebook as "low power" notebook in an R.V. (Wohnmobil) ...

Comment: I forgot: I do not quite understand the canopy error messages .. Enthought has the same info however they did not yet answer ...